# c sorting large struct array and printing to screen

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct, structure

I'm having trouble sorting a struct array and then printing it to screen. When I run the code in Visual Studio 2012, it doesn't print AT ALL. I've spent hours figuring it out, and debugging mode is very buggy. I really need to know why it isn't doing what I tell it to do.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct RandStruct
{
int year;
char string[31];
int frequency;
};

struct RandStruct randArray[150000];

int main(void)
{

int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < 150000; i++)
{
    randArray[i].year = 150000 - i;
    strcpy(randArray[i].string, "test");
    randArray[i].frequency = i;
}

for (i = 1; i < 150000; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 150000 - i; j++)
    {
        if (randArray[j].year > randArray[j+1].year)
        {
            struct RandStruct temp = randArray[j];
            randArray[j] = randArray[j+1];
            randArray[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 150000; i++)
{
    printf("%d,%s,%d\n", randArray[i].year, randArray[i].string, randArray[i].frequency);
}

return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you run in the debugger and break, are you still in your nested for loop?  Your sorting loops will run 22.5 BILLION times.

Comment: Bubblesort? Must you?

Comment: Ah! But it is doing what you tell it to do!

Comment: @Joe I'm not sure what you mean? When I run it, the console pops up, and the cursor is blinking; however, I can't input anything in it.... Can you tell me how to fix this

Comment: @Chrislast it's just taking a very long time because bubble sort is slow on such sizes.

Comment: Do you have PHz processor? ;-)

Comment: Yeah, start by knocking a few orders of magnitude off your counter, all the way down to 15.  Then use a symbolic constant instead of a literal (i.e., `#define MAX 15 ... for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++ )...`.  Verify that your algorithm works (or doesn't) with a small sample set first.

Comment: @interjay What sort should I use if I need it done fast. The sort is just the first part of my program. Right after that I'll be using the array for a lot of other stuff.

Comment: Also, realize that printing 150000 lines to standard out is going to really give your console issues.  (You'll find that the output is MUCH faster if you redirect output to a file, instead.)

Comment: You could use the `qsort` library function, which uses a fast(er than bubble sort) algorithm.  You'll have to write a comparison function, but that's pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Chrislast: The specific problem you're running up against is that bubble sort (the algorithm you're using) has an execution time that's O(n^2); that is, the amount of time that it takes to run is proportional to the square of the number of items to be sorted.  The square of 150000 is 22.5 billion; even on a modern processor, it'll take more than a few seconds to sort that many records using that algorithm.

Comment: @JohnBode Thank you sir, now I'll remember it in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For sorting, you should use the qsort function instead of reinventing the wheel.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int my_compar(const void *a, const void *b) {
  const struct RandStruct *aa = a;
  const struct RandStruct *bb = b;
  if(aa->year < bb->year) return -1;
  if(aa->year == bb->year) return 0;
  return 1;
}

int main(void) {
   ... other stuff ...
   size_t size = sizeof(struct RandStruct);
   qsort(randArray, sizeof(randArray)/size, size, my_compar);
}
```

Comment: Listen to @Random832.  He is your guru!

Comment: arguments of `my_compar` must be `const`